# Why MariaDB10.0.15 too many ‘show variables ’?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, heidisql

when i show mariadb-Servercommand use heidisSQL,'show variables' is 26% percent in all command execute , why too many 'show variables' in my mariadb-Server,my config have problems or my sql query have problems(in my query no use this command)?<>

###############################HeidiSQL data########

command-type___numbers___average/h___average/s___percent
select___5042749___30362.9___8.4___66.5%
show variables___1995998___12018.1___3.3___26.3%
insert___268491___1616.6___0.4___3.5%
update___140663___846.9___0.2___1.9%
others.....

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the General log briefly.  You will probably find that HeidiSQL is executing the SHOWs on your behalf.  This is a common feature/problem of third-party software -- they like to check for things that might have (but never are) changed out from under them.

It looks like there are about 4 SHOWs per 'real' query.  Complain to Heidi.